# Phonegap: Object #<Navigator> has no method 'vibrate'

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap, vibration

When I try `navigator.vibrate()`, I receive

> TypeError: Object # < Navigator > has no method 'vibrate'

I'm using phonegap cli 8.0.0, build for android.
My config.xml:

```
< plugin source="npm" spec="~3.0.1" name="cordova-plugin-vibration" / >
```

trying with:

```
< feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/vibration" / >
```

same result.

Comment: One more interesting thing... I've renamed AKP file to ZIP end examined contents. All plugins described in config.xml are in plugins folder except cordova-plugin-vibration. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you open cordova-plugin-vibration\README.md you will see this:

The Android webview (API level 19 and up) supports the [W3C Vibration API](https://www.w3.org/TR/vibration/) natively and therefore, the Android specific implementation of this plugin has been dropped.

*This is a cause why you don't see this plugin in APK file.*

If you check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/vibrate you will see that vibration API was implemented in Chrome v32.

This page https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview says that Android 4.4 (KitKat) was shipped with Chrome for Android version 30. The updated WebView shipped with Android 4.4.3 has the version number 33.0.0.0.

So, on Android versions less than 4.4.3 you will not have vibration API and will get this error "TypeError: Object # < Navigator > has no method 'vibrate'"

You did not mentioned Android version, but I guess you should have 4.4 to 4.4.2.

**What to do**

I suggest to use cordova-plugin-vibration version 2.* where they do not rely on Vibration API in browser.

For example, run this in project folder:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-vibration@2.1.6 --save
```